# Требуется закрывать виджет QMessageBox.warning спустя 1-2 секунды после его запуска

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qmessagebox

Мне требуется создать функцию, в которой создается `QMessageBox.warning` и закрывать это сообщение спустя несколько секунд.

Возможно нужно обязательно создавать дополнительный новый тип `QMessageBox` в котором нужно будет создавать таймер.

Если кто-то сможет помочь, буду признателен. В виджете `QMessageBox.warning` требуется просто выводить текст `"объект обнаружен"`.

Answer (score 3):

```
msg = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Warning, "title", "message text")
msg.show()
QTimer.singleShot(  3000, lambda : msg.close()  )
```

QMessageBox - это обычный класс дилогового окна. Чтобы открыть его (и оставить открытым) нужно открывать с помощью `show`, а не `exec`, как диалоги.

Answer (score 1):

Небольшой полигон для показа/скрытия очереди сообщений:

```
import sys
import random

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QDateTime

# Класс сообщения
# Содержит поле сообщения и абсолютное время жизни после 
# Наступления которого сообщение удаляется
class Message():
    def __init__(self, message, time):
        self._time = time
        self.box = QMessageBox()
        self.box.setText(message)
        self.box.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.NoButton)

        x = random.randint(300, 600)
        y = random.randint(300, 600)
        self.box.move(x, y)

        self.box.show()

    # Абсолютное время/отсечка
    def time(self):
        return self._time

    # Закрыть QMessageBox
    def close(self):
        self.box.close()

# Класс очереди сообщений
class MessageQueue():
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = [] # очередь сообщений в виде списка

        # Таймер проверки очереди сообщений
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.timeout)
        self.timer.start(100)

    # Добавить сообщение в очередь
    def append(self, message, dt=2000):
        # Создаем сообщение и сразу же его показываем
        # Время отсечки/жизни = текущее время + дельта dt
        self.q.append(Message(message, QDateTime.currentDateTime().toMSecsSinceEpoch() + dt))

    # Проверяем очередь на наличие сообщений, 
    # которые надо скрыть и удалить из очереди
    def timeout(self):
        currentTime = QDateTime.currentDateTime().toMSecsSinceEpoch()
        for m in self.q:
            if m.time() <= currentTime:
                m.close()
                self.q.remove(m)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    mq = MessageQueue()

    # Создаем 5 фиктивных сообщений в очереди
    for i in range(5):
        mq.append('Объект обнаружен!', i * 1000)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```